# Get different values Mysql and multiply PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (**MySQL**) that contains rows for lessons. In each of these lines, there is a counter page views, and the duration of the lesson. I am able to get out a function (**PHP**) that will tell me the time spent watching a lesson, and add all the other lessons watched.

My table **articles**

```
id | time | views
-----------------
1  |  5   | 20
2  |  40  | 0
3  |  30  | 6
```

the total is: (5 * 20) + (40 * 0) + (30 * 6) = 280 minutes, and convert in hours: 4,6667 h (4h with no decimal)

My function works, but this is not the right calculation. This function multiply le total views with the total minutes.
I know that we must first multiply each course, with the number of views associated, and add up all these results together. But I do not know how.

```
function hoursLessons() {

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'myDB');


// Total Views

$views_sql = "SELECT SUM(views) as total FROM articles";
$views_result = $con->query($views_sql);
$views_row = $views_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$views_total = $views_row['total'];

// Total Minutes

$minutes_sql = "SELECT SUM(time) as total FROM articles";
$minutes_result = $con->query($minutes_sql);
$minutes_row = $minutes_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$minutes_total = $minutes_row['total'];

// Convert Minutes to Hours

$hours = floor($minutes_total / 60);
$totalHours = $hours * $views_total;

return $totalHours;

$views_result->free();
$minutes_result->free();
$con->close();

}
```

Comment: So - what's the exact question?

Comment: what you need exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use 1 query to get the result of 280:

```
select sum(time_views) from (select id,time*views as time_views from articles) a
```

and if you want to get the hours from the query itself you can use:

```
select round(sum(time_views)/60) from (select id,time*views as time_views from articles) a
```

the above will give 5 hours, but below will give 4 hours:

```
select floor(sum(time_views)/60) from (select id,time*views as time_views from articles) a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem

```
<?php

function hoursLessons() {

    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'myDB');

    $sql = "SELECT (`time` * `views`) AS `times` FROM `articles`";
    $query = $con->query($sql);

    $minutes_total = 0;
    while ($result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $minutes_total += $result["times"];
    }

    // Convert Minutes to Hours

    $totalHours = floor($minutes_total / 60);

    return $totalHours;
}

echo hoursLessons();
```